# How to change collection column value in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel collection that's like this:

```
$loan = Loans::where([
            ['OL_TEMP_APP_NO', $appNo]
        ])
        ->get();
```

The `$loan` collection returns `principal, terms, code`. The code corresponds to a string. Example 1 = new, 2 = processing, 3 = approved.

How do I parse the values under `code` before sending them to the view?

Comment: are you using mysql as database driver?

Comment: @TsaiKoga I am, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE WHEN` to convert the integer to string code:

```php
$loan = Loans::where([
            ['OL_TEMP_APP_NO', $appNo]
        ])
        ->select('principal', 'terms', DB::raw("
           (CASE code
            WHEN 2 THEN 'processing'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'approved'
            ELSE 'new' END) AS code
        "))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Is it secure to use DB::raw? Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question but I'm just making sure.

Comment: @ehmhrgelcighsawmlv there are no parameters from external in DB::raw().  It is safe. There is no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: It returns an error ```syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'``` This is my code ```$loan = Loans::select('BR_ID', 'ClientID', 'PURPOSE', 'PAMT', 'TERMS', 'PPMT_MODE', 'PPMT_MFAC', 'PPMT_MOD2', 'INT_RATE', 'PEN_RATE', 'OL_TEMP_APP_NO', 'APPLICATION_NO', 'ActivityListID', 'DateRequested', 'DateApproved', 'ClientRemarks', DB::raw("
           (CASE SLT_CODE
            WHEN 12 THEN 'Motorcycle Loan'
            ELSE 'new' END) AS SLT_CODE
        ")->where([
      ['OL_TEMP_APP_NO', $appNo]
     ])
     ->first();```

Comment: it's okay now, what's needed was just to change DB:: to Loans::

Answer (score 1):

if you already know the value of `code`, or `code` will always have some fixed values, then you can use like following:

```
public function getAll(){
   // ...
    $loans = Loans::where([['OL_TEMP_APP_NO', $appNo]])->get();
    $data = [];
    foreach($loans as $loan){
        $code = Code::getValue($loan->code);
        $data[] = [
              'principal' => $loan->principal, 
              'terms' => $loan->terms, 
              'code' => ($loan->code == 1) ? 'new' : ( ($loan->code == 2) ? 'processing' : 'approved') 
              ]
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just chose TsaiKoga's over yours because I don't have to create another function.